# Adding pdf to svelte component

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I want to add a pdf to my svelte component.

I'm using the same syntax as normal HTML but this dose not work.

```html
<iframe src="./stadgar.pdf" width="500" height="1000" ></iframe>
```

What I get is an image of how my error page looks like.

The only solution I see here is to install a package like `svelte-pdf`.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the browser supports it, you can link to PDFs in an `iframe`, but you cannot just reference files like that.

If you have static assets, they should be imported in the script. Unless the type is known to Vite, [add `?url` to the import](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#importing-asset-as-url) to make Vite emit the asset and give you a valid URL:

```html
<script>
    import pdfUrl from './stadgar.pdf?url';
</script>

<iframe src={pdfUrl} width="500" height="1000" title="PDF"/>
```